# Conditional Expectation with respect to two Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Consider the quantity
$$
\mathrm E[U \mid S,T].
$$
Is this shorthand for
$$
\mathrm E[U \mid \sigma(S) \otimes \sigma(T)]?
$$
If so, the defining characteristics are that $\mathrm E[U \mid S,T]$ is $\sigma(S) \otimes \sigma(T)$-measurable and 
$$
\mathrm E[\mathbf 1_A \, \mathrm E[U \mid S,T]] = \mathrm E[\mathbf 1_A \, U]
$$
for all $A \in \sigma(S) \otimes \sigma(T)$.

Then, consider a set $B \in \sigma(T)$.  Using the above definitions I don't quite see how we can write
$$
\mathrm E[\mathbf 1_B \, \mathrm E[U \mid S,T]] = \mathrm E[\mathbf 1_B \, U]
$$
unless $B \in \sigma(S) \otimes \sigma(T)$, which doesn't seem to make sense.  This was done in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97422/probability-distribution-of-functions-of-random-variables).  The alternatives I can think of are
$$
\mathrm E[U \mid \sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T)], \quad \text{or} \quad \mathrm E[U \mid \sigma(S) \cup\sigma(T)],
$$
but the union isn't necessarily a sigma-algebra, and the intersection still wouldn't help unless $B \in \sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T)$, too.

Comment: It is short-hand for $\sigma(S,T)$.

Comment: @Calculon I guess I'm familiar with such sigma-algebras...I guess it holds that $\sigma(T) \subset \sigma(S,T)$?

Comment: Yes. Actually, $\sigma(S,T) = \sigma(\{\omega: S(\omega) \in \mathcal{B}_s, T(\omega) \in \mathcal{B}_t\})$. Here $\mathcal{B}_s$ and $\mathcal{B}_t$ are Borel sets.

Comment: @Calculon Ah, okay.  Just to compare, $\sigma(S) \otimes \sigma(T) = \sigma(\{(\omega_1,\omega_2) \in \Omega \times \Omega : S(\omega_1) \in \mathcal{B}_s, T(\omega_2) \in \mathcal{B}_t\})$?

Comment: I am not so sure if that equality is true. (Probably it is.) I always interpreted the product sigma-algebra as simply the Cartesian product of the two sigma-algebras.

Comment: @Calculon Actually, I don't see how $B \in \sigma(T) \implies B \in \sigma(S,T)$ unless $B \in \sigma(S)$ as well...am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Take $B_s = \mathbb{R}$ (or however your r.v.s are valued) in the expression for $\sigma(S,T)$.

Comment: @Calculon Sorry, I skipped breakfast this morning.  Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: $$E(U\mid S,T)=E(U\mid\sigma(\sigma(S)\cup\sigma(T)))$$